# Simple JavaScript Loop which updates on InnerHTML Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, innerhtml

When the page loads, I want to generate a JavaScript loop. The total number of items is depending the PHP string already on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Generation(){
    var loopTotal = <?=$TotalNumberOfRows?>;
    var innerToUpdate=$("#loopItemSet");

    var page=0;
    for (var i=0;i<=<?=$TotalNumberOfRows?>;i+=24)
    {
        page++;
        // document.write(i);
        innerToUpdate.innerHTML="<a href='link.php?go="+i+"'> page number "+page+"</a>";
    }       
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    Generation();   
});

</script>
```

It should return three links since 24, goes into 52, three times.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the value of `$TotalNumberOfRows` is.

Comment: @Jasper, from my understanding that's a dynamically created number.

Comment: @FrankB, yes but instead of telling us what the problem is, he is muttering about some numbers, which make no sense if not all numbers are known

Comment: 24 goes into 52 three times? No, 24 * 3 = 72.

Comment: `$TotalNumberOfRows` could be 52 in this example. @Batman typo on remainders..

Comment: @jasper Actually while I agree that the question was unclear, knowing that value is irrelevant to the core of the question.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid I know, if you start with zero `i` would be [0,24,48] which is three but saying "24 goes into 52 three times" is just wrong. WRONG!

Comment: @FrankB, yep, I gave up while trying to decipher his code because I was lacking information, but yes, I could have solved the problem without deciphering the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This row override the `innerHTML` of your element in each iteration. You could simply add a `+` like this:

```
innerToUpdate.innerHTML += "<a href='link.php?go="+i+"'> page number "+page+"</a>";
```

or collect all entries in a string first and then update the HTML content of that element just once:

```
    function Generation(){
        var loopTotal = <?=$TotalNumberOfRows?>;
        var innerToUpdate=$("#loopItemSet");
        // var innerToUpdate=$(".loopItemSet"); // for multiple elements.

        var page=0, content = '';
        for (var i=0;i<=<?=$TotalNumberOfRows?>;i+=24)
        {
            page++;
            // document.write(i);
            content += "<a href='link.php?go="+i+"'> page number "+page+"</a>";
        }
        innerToUpdate.html( content );
    }
```

<sup>I replaced you call to `innerHTML` with jQuery's [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2). In my opinion, if you use jQuery, use it wherever needed.</sup>

Comment: If I had more than on `<div id="loopItemSet">` how do I do it so it inserts to all on the page?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid `id` means unique, so you should not have multiple elements of that id. Use, e.g., `class` instead. Then just select all those elements and call `html()` for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You want use jQuery's append

Instead of this:

```
    innerToUpdate.innerHTML="<a href="link.php?go="+i+""> page number "+page+"</a>";
```

try this:

```
    innerToUpdate.append('<a href="link.php?go='+i+'"> page number '+page+'</a>');
```

Check the quotes in that line, you had some badly nested double quotes that I edited.

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear but I'm assuming you're only getting one link instead of 3 and want to know why. It's here:

```
    for (var i=0;i<=<?=$TotalNumberOfRows?>;i+=24)
    {
        page++;
        // document.write(i);
        innerToUpdate.innerHTML="<a href='link.php?go="+i+"'> page number "+page+"</a>";
    }
```

Should read:

```
  for (var i=0;i<=<?=$TotalNumberOfRows?>;i+=24)
        {
            page++;
            // document.write(i);
            innerToUpdate.innerHTML+="<a href='link.php?go="+i+"'> page number "+page+"</a>";
        }
```

Your current code is resetting the html each time instead of concatenating onto it.